# Не работает flex-wrap wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

По теории должно складываться в 2 линии, а переносятся только одно слово

```css
.header__container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 115px;
  .header__logo {
    padding: 23px 20px 0 0;
  }
  .logo {
    flex: 0 1 220px;
  }
  .logo__item {}
  .header__menu {}
  .menu {}
  .menu__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .menu__item {
    line-height: 115px;
  }
  .menu__item:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #11749e;
  }
  .menu__link {
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 28 / 16 * 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 77px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
  }
  .header__social {}
  .social-header {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .social-header__link {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  }
  .social-header__link:last-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .social-header__fb {}
  .social-header__tw {}
  .social-header__sk {}
  .social-header__in {}
}
```

```html
<div class='header__container _container'>
  <div class="header__logo logo">
    <a href="#" class="logo__item"><img src="img/first/Logo.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <nav class="header__menu menu">
    <ul class="menu__list">
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Pages</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Extensions</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Tutorials</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="header__social social-header">
    <a href="#" class="social-header__link"><img src="img/first/fb.png" alt="" class="social-header__fb"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social-header__link"><img src="img/first/tw.png" alt="" class="social-header__tw"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social-header__link"><img src="img/first/sk.png" alt="" class="social-header__sk"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social-header__link"><img src="img/first/in.png" alt="" class="social-header__in"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: там большое меню]

Comment: Выложите полный код. Сейчас из описания непонятно, в чем именно проблема, а из кода тоже не ясно. Я попробовал в вашем коде менять ширину у .menu__list, тогда элементы внутри нормально переносятся на следующую строку.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Alex2750/pen/NWwvmqQ